# Electric vent opener for wet environment?

Tags: electrical

I'm not quite sure if this is appropriate for this forum, but let me explain.

I have a greenhouse, that I keep warm during the winter with an electric heater, controlled by a thermostat. The thermostat controls the power to two power-sockets; one turns on when the temperature is too low, the other when it gets too hot. I already have an electric fan-heater for heating during the winter, but I need something that will open a roof vent in the summer, when it gets too warm. I imagine something like a simple, magnetic on-off thing, that opens the vent when the power comes on and passively let it fall back down again when the power is off - and it needs to withstand daily soaking from watering.

But I don't even know what to call such a thing, so I can search for it - any suggestions?

Comment: A linear actuator?

Comment: @SolarMike That sounds like it could very well be just the thing. Now I just need one that doesn't explode in blue smoke when it gets wet.

Comment: Mount it so it won't get wet.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer for your question but a common solution for ventilating greenhouses is a wax piston which expands when heated up.  The temperature is not controllable though since it is set by the properties on the wax used.

Comment: @SolarMike Ah, well, that is the thing - I've installed sprinklers for watering with the explicit purpose of soaking everything :-)

Comment: @Jonathan I know the kind you mean - they might work, but as you say, the won't be as controllable as I hope

Comment: So, you go to the effort of sprinklers but don’t direct yhem where they would be yhe most effective like the plant roots.

Comment: @SolarMike Well, the purpose is not just to wet the roots - this is an orchid greenhouse, and I want to wet the glass and the floor to raise the humidity, so I use a kind of spray-nozzles to mist the whole interior.

Comment: Well, I am sure you can find ones that are waterproof now you have been given an idea as to what to search for. Do remember shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: I would use a wet rated Linear actuator like on a motorized swing gate the last one I installed was 12v but I have installed 120v versions these guys live in the rain, ask anyone that lives in Oregon or the PNW.